# unbind() method does not exist

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using jasmine to test an application that runs by AngularJs. My function is simple which checks for activate value and scroll. Whenever the value of 'scroll' is more than the value of 'activate' the function should be `unbind` from scroll event. like:

```
scope.fA = function () {
  if (scroll >= activate) {
    angular.element($window).unbind('scroll', scope.fA);
  }
}; 

angular.element($window).bind('scroll', scope.fA);
```

Can you please tell me the right syntax for `spyOn(angular.element, 'unbind');` and `expect(angular.element.unbind).toHaveBeenCalled();` 
This is how I am testing it and which is obviously wrong:

```
it('should call unbind method', function() {
  spyOn(angular.element, 'unbind');
  triggerEventOnElement('scroll', $window);
  expect(angular.element.unbind).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Can't you directly use the `$window` service instead of using an element selector?

Comment: no, it does not find it. this is the error `unbind() method does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bit tricky to test if a function is bounded or not. In fact, I have no clue about the right syntax, but you can do test it with another approach. Instead of bounding the `scope.fA` to `scroll` event, you better create a temp var and assign that to be `bind` to scroll. like:

```
var refFA;
scope.FA = function () {
  if (scroll >= activate) {
   angular.element($window).unbind('scroll', refFA);
  }
};
refFA = scope.FA;
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', refFA);
```

Then instead of spying on `unbind` you better spy on `scope.FA`like:

```
spyOn(scope, 'FA');
```

then for checking if the function was unbinded just add any class to your element, trigger the scroll and expect that the class is there, then remove the class and trigger again, then expect the class doesn't exists. Yes, it seems so complicated and not clear. but just check the bellow final code:

```
var refFA;
scope.FA = function () {
  elem.addClass('fan-some-class');
  if (scroll >= activate) {
    angular.element($window).unbind('scroll', refFA);
  }
};
refFA = scope.FA;
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', refFA);
```

and the test:

```
it('should unbind method', function() {
  triggerEventOnElement('scroll', $window);
  expect(elem.hasClass('fan-some-class')).toBe(true);
  elem.removeClass('fan-some-class');
  triggerEventOnElement('scroll', $window);
  expect(elem.hasClass('fan-some-class')).toBe(false);
});
```

This is a bit more code to write, but I think if you don't have any idea about spying on the `unbind` method then this can be the solution. Of course it is not the best one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and it works. Since, there is no any other solution I think I can go with that :)